# Password confirmation field -- extension or composition

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation, viewmodel

Good day!

I've, say, simple LINQ2SQL entity called `User`. I need a profile page where password confirmation field needed. I don't want to add this field to my db or entity. I'd like to add ViewModel class. My firt attempt is like this:

```
[MyClassLevelAttributeToCheckPasswordAndPasswordConfirmation]
public class ProfileUser
{
    public User UserEntity {get; set;}

    [DisplayName("Password confirmation")]
    public string PasswordConfirmation {get; set;}
}
```

My `User` class has its own validation and metadata.

Is there any better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use any of your model classes inside the views. Use plain view models:

```
[MyClassLevelAttributeToCheckPasswordAndPasswordConfirmation]
public class ChangePasswordViewModel
{
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Password confirmation")]
    public string PasswordConfirmation {get; set;}
}
```

As you can see we put only the properties relevant to changing a password view (or whatever view you are implementing). This way you can have a fine grained validation control in the context of the given view. [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) could help you to get back your model from the view model.

Comment: I need other properties of my `User` on this page. I do use AutoMapper, but I'd like to have validation attached to `User` too? Does this make sense?

Comment: @artvolk, add only required user properties to the view model and attach validation attributes to them. As far as the validation of the User object is concerned this should be done in your service layer.